# What do you automate and what do you audiosuite?

Tags: automation, audiosuite, processing, workflow

What sorts of things do you automate and what do you like to audiosuite process?

EQ? Reverbs? Volume?

I know volume is a no-brainer because people love using faders to automate volume, but who knows - someone might find gain processing easier and faster...

I'm always automating reverb presets, volume, EQ settings (such as low-pass and high-pass, cuts, etc.)

I'm curious if I can hasten my workflow if one of you have a better suggestion as to what you do.

Comment: You pretty much have to automate everything with Protools LE, 40 tracks.  I automate volume, eq, send level, and panning.  I audiosuite for on the fly changes.

Comment: @thewoosh Thanks for answering, post it as an answer next time so I can up-vote it! When you say on the fly changes, do you mean for the director or tweaks once you are finished?

Answer (score 4):

My goal is to get away with using as little dsp as possible, so...

I'll audiosuite

- simple changes that I know I want to print like HP or gain
- noise reduction (to eliminate messing with delay compensation)
- things I can't process in real-time: doppler, normalize, reverse, etc.

I'll automate & re-record new clips that use any effect like delay, freq modulation, phase, distortion, etc. in order to save the burden of an insert for one or two clips. But either when audiosuiting (new word?) or re-recording I always keep the original (either clip muted or track inactive) in order to be able to backtrack.

In the final mix I'll automate it all

- EQ
- Dynamics
- Volume
- Reverbs
- Sends

Answer (score 3):

I automate things i know i'll need to tweak (and suspect the director may want to change) in the mix, which is basically everything! Dialogue eq, volume, reverbs, foley eq...
I'll only really use the audiosuite for a couple of things:

Noise reduction (but i'll leave the original clip, muted, on a worktrack).

Effects that i want to treat with eq or something crazier, but don't want to waste the insert for a 1-off occurrence. Again, i'll leave the original nearby, and maybe save the settings i treat it with.

Also, before going to mix, i check out all my temp volume automation and audiosuite everything with gain so it'll sound ok with the faders flat.

Comment: lol. I should've just waited to answer and up voted yours @Sound Understanding!

Comment: @Steve Do you only up-vote once per topic?

Comment: @Justin Huss no, I'll vote more than once. It's just that we basically said the same thing and Sound Understanding must've posted while I was responding.

Comment: @Steve Urban - Haha, great minds etc. etc. But i think you summed it up better than i did.

Answer (score 1):

@ryan, Im still learning, still in an audio school, still finishing up my demo reel, so my workflow isn't the best yet but its getting there.  By on the fly changes meaning when I want to quickly alter sounds and audition them rather than using a plug-in as an insert.

Answer (score 1):

I automate volume and EQ as I need, and effect sends.  As a huge fan of dub music, I've learned to love automating delay and reverbs, and overdrives, but I almost never get to do that in sound design.

Answer (score 1):

AS for editing, RTAS for premixing/mixing. Now we could talk about what is each task about...

Comment: You mean like more questions can be asked about each task?

Answer (score 0):

I actually just thought of why you could use Audiosuite.  If you are EQing in relation to the HRTF (Head Related Transfer Function), applying EQ to only one channel in a stereo track would be beneficial.

Comment: I get it, although I don't know if it's standard practice to EQ one channel only? Interesting point :)